# c# RegEx - multiple replacement of terms separated by just one character

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do a string replacement but the challenge is that I don't want to replace the string if it is part of another word.  The target strings can consist of letters, numbers and periods.  So for example, if the target string is "Old1.Var" and the replacement is "newVar", then I want to do the replacement when the string looks like "This is an Old1.Var", but not when it is "This is an Old1.Var**iable**".  The target string (i.e. variable) can occur multiple times within the string and each one needs to be replaced.  The target string can be at the beginning, middle or end of the string.

The closest regex expression that I've been able to come up with is:
(^|[^\w\d.])Old1.Var([^\w\d.]|$).  This takes care of all my test cases except where there is only one character separating two sequential target terms.

But because of the way the matching works, this doesn't work if there is only one character between the terms.  In other words, "Old1.Var+Old1.Var" just matches on the first term and doesn't replace the second term.  If I put spaces around the +, then this works correctly but not with a single character between the terms.

My test cases are as follows (each line below is a separate case):

```
Old1.Var,xxxx,Old1.Var,xxxx,Old1.Var
EmbededOld1.Var,xxxx,EmbededOld1.Var,xxxx,EmbededOld1.Var
Old1.VarEmbeded,xxxx,Old1.VarEmbeded,xxxx,Old1.VarEmbeded
Old1.Var@Old1.Var+(Old1.Var/Old1.Var*Old1.Var)-Old1.Var
```

The expected results are the following:

```
newVar,xxxx,newVar,xxxx,newVar
EmbededOld1.Var,xxxx,EmbededOld1.Var,xxxx,EmbededOld1.Var
Old1.VarEmbeded,xxxx,Old1.VarEmbeded,xxxx,Old1.VarEmbeded
newVar@newVar+(newVar/newVar*newVar)-newVar
```

For reference, the C# code that I'm using is the following:

```
var resultStr = Regex.Replace(variableString, @"(^|[^\w\d.])" + oldVariableName + @"([^\w\d.]|$)", "$1" + newVariableName + "$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries with lookarounds, or just lookarounds:

```
var resultStr = Regex.Replace(variableString, 
        @"(?<![\w.])" + Regex.Escape(oldVariableName) + @"(?![\w.])", 
        newVariableName.Replace("$", "$$"), 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

Here,

- `@"(?<![\w.])"` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a word char or `.` immediately before the current location
- `Regex.Escape(oldVariableName)` - the value is a literal string, thus all the special chars must be escaped
- `@"(?![\w.])"` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char or `.` immediately after the current location.
- `newVariableName.Replace("$", "$$")` - here, all `$` in the `newVariableName`  are doubled because a `$` followed with a digit forms a backreference, but `newVariableName` must be treated as a literal string.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%5Cw.%5D%29Old1%5C.Var%28%3F!%5B%5Cw.%5D%29&i=Old1.Var%2Cxxxx%2COld1.Var%2Cxxxx%2COld1.Var%0D%0AEmbededOld1.Var%2Cxxxx%2CEmbededOld1.Var%2Cxxxx%2CEmbededOld1.Var%0D%0AOld1.VarEmbeded%2Cxxxx%2COld1.VarEmbeded%2Cxxxx%2COld1.VarEmbeded%0D%0AOld1.Var%40Old1.Var%2B%28Old1.Var%2FOld1.Var*Old1.Var%29-Old1.Var&r=newVar):[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and demo.  I was also missing those extra elements (Escape and Replace) that would have been an issue with other test cases.  I was using regex101.com and the behavior in .NET is just a little different so your reference to regexstorm.net also helped.